# Apache .htacess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im trying to render a specific file as PHP with params using htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "a.html" gen.php$1 [L]
```

i got "Internal Server Error". I have seen a lot of people get this error when there is endless recursion, but here it is not the case.

gen.php works and found on mysubdomain.mydomain.com/gen.php
.htacess found on mysubdomain.mydomain.com/.htacess

What is the problem? Is there a way to debug such issues?

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do mention from which url to which url you want to rewrite as samples in your question.

Comment: Are you sure `mod-rewrite` is enabled on your server?

Comment: mod-rewrite is enabled.

Comment: "RewriteRule "a.html" index.php [L]" works for some reason but with gen.php not

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: Please share more details, like the exact error message put to your server's error log

Comment: @AmitVerma no. Thats all.

Comment: @NicoHaase Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mysubdomain.mydomain.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: In general: you _can not_ develop something in a web environment without monitoring the http server's error log file .That would be like flying in a narrow cave with your eyes blindfolded. Sure, you can do it. But it would be something pretty stupid to try.

Comment: @Emma92 please check your **server** error log, usually that does not contain such an error message, but a more detailed one

Answer (score 0):

$1 is usually content of the capturing group 1 defined with (). In your rule, $1 does not exist as no capturing group used.

You can test this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "a.html" gen.php [L]
```

Without $1.

Comment: OP is getting a 500 internal server error.  So the `$1` is not the case here the rule should work even with it.

Comment: Sorry I've not tested it.